# Most cost-efficient way to implement USB full-speed host?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, usb-host

I need to a device which can act as a USB host to send various chunks of static binary data periodically to a full-peed USB serial peripheral of FT232 type (RS-232-ish UART).

I was thinking maybe using a microcontroller that supports USB host and accessing a serial flash for the binary data.

It'll be a custom board (vs. modules) and I need to keep the part count as low as possible.

Am I approaching this the right way?  Any recommendations that fit these requirements?  I'm afraid I'm not sure really where to start on a project like this..

Comment: How many of these are you planning to build? If it's <100 and there is no other reason why you want to build it from scratch, throw a Raspberry Pi , a Linux kernel and some minimal scripting at it and you are done. That's extremely cost-efficient because the engineering you need to do is about 10 hours or so.

Comment: @Janka Yeah, this definitely needs to be a custom solution.  It will be a product to be sold.

Comment: What do you mean "USB serial host"? USB is Universal **Serial**  Bus already. USB is not UART. What do you mean "a USB serial peripheral"? Is it already made by someone, or what?

Comment: @AliChen The peripheral is a USB device that emulates an RS-232 connection, like and FT-232 or something.  I need to connect to that as a "host".

Comment: So why do you need any USB at all? Why not use your original usual UART capabilities if any usual MCU, and connect to your UART destination directly, without any middle UART->USB->UART transformations?

Comment: @AliChen Because I don't have control over the peripheral, and it implements UART over USB.  I have to work with what it uses.

Comment: Ok, then what you mean is that you need a USB host. Typical USB host is a PC. Are you saying that you need a programmable USB host at a lowest possible cost?

Comment: @AliChen I only need to implement a single virtual UART.  I wanted that to be clear in case that affects the cost.  I don't need linux or USB 3 or HID or Flash drives.

Comment: Then I am afraid it won't be that easy. You need to search for "embedded micro-controller" or SoC with "USB OTG" functionality.

Comment: Look at something like the Kinetis KL25Z/KL26Z/KL27Z - very cheap to implement yourself, if you want something premade as a proof of concept first get one in the form of a Teensy LC, Kinetis freedom board, etc.

Comment: This appears to be a shopping question about cheapest MCU with USB host capabilities. Many manufacturers offer such chips, TI, Cypress, Microchip, NXP, Broadcom etc. This question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Write up an answer and I'll accept this.  This looks like a workable MCU and nice bonus that the Teensy LC is implemented with it.

Comment: Rolled back the edit, as FT232 was a 3rd party **guess** not mentioned by the asker at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, why would you do this? The original terminology is not right, and the FT232 was mentioned in clarifications by OP, look above. Please unroll your edit.

Comment: Please note that the Teensy LC does not have any USB connection for host function. As a matter of fact, the NXP development kit FRDM-KL25Z (avaliable at DigiKey) does not have proper provisions to function as host either (no VBUS as source).

Comment: @AliChen - no, the ONLY mention on this page of FT232 was by you, apart from mine pointing out that fact.  This is easily confirmed with a simple text search that any browser can do.

Comment: @AliChen In actuality both the Teensy-LC and the freedom KL25Z are routinely used as USB hosts.  Typically they need a connector adapter and a jumper for power.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, can't you read?  
"The peripheral is a USB device that emulates an RS-232 connection, **like and FT-232 or something**. I need to connect to that as a "host". – Sam Washburn 19 hours ago" I strongly suggest you to back off. Is there any moderator over here?

Comment: Thought only - look to see if OTG devices work for you in any way

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the simplest way to get the capabilities you need is to use the Raspberry Pi Zero.
This will support your USB requirements and Raspbian will auto discover your USB\serial.
It will support a couple of buttons if you need them. 
There is a Lite version of Raspian that is a little over 300 MB.
It also has plenty of space for your data files on the plug in SD card, and an easy 'C' or Python development environment. 
Best of all it costs $5.00 ...who could beat that ..

It will run from a simple power supply (USB style power cable) 5 V @2 A

Assuming you have a simple serial protocol you could develop the handshake and data protocol on the 'Pi with a screen and keyboard or over a remote ssh connection, or you could also simply plug you device into a PC and develop a Python script to do you task.
A 'Pi takes about 10 seconds to boot (about the same as an Arduino bootloader timeout) which I assume may be viable.

Comment: This is in actuality a terrible idea.  If the raspberry pi were what it *should have been* it might be a good one.  But the pi's reliance on a fragile and relatively costly micro SD card kills both the economics and reliability of the solution.  This will set you back about $8 plus a lot of headache, an MCU solution will be under $4, far more robust as it essentially has no corruptible state, relatively instant booting, etc.

Comment: The OP already said he needed (serial) flash to store data so I don't see the problem. There are absolutely millions of smartphones (and Raspberry Pi's) out there that use microSD cards and I have yet to hear of mass reliability problems. A 1GB microSD will cost under $3,your $8 is way off.    Certainly I accept that the boot time is longer for the 'PI, but what microprocessor on a board with sufficient Flash and USB support for his purpose can you point to for less than the cost of the 'Pi. I can barely buy an Arduino Nano for this sort of price!

Comment: The MCU version will be $4 with a boatload of up front engineering costs that will require a lot of units to bring the total cost below  8.

Comment: Correct @whatsisname. But I quoted retail prices for the Pi, if there are large quantities involved you know the price will drop. If you only need a few 10's or 100's of units it's hard to justify the expense of custom boards/design.  It's not only the hardware NRE costs that make special design of a MCU board/software solution hard, but you have tougher software decisions to make and tougher support processes (like versioning the software or data).

Comment: You obviously have no idea of the difference between serial flash and sd card reliability in something like a pi or how messy the pi approach is in practice overall, nor how simple the MCU one is.  Try both and you'll learn a time consuming lesson.  For the asker though - just use the MCU, having personally quickly built that trivial device, the engineering cost will be far less than with the pi by the time you have something you can use, it will be more reliable, lower power, faster to start, and cheaper.

Comment: Having designed product (at test and mass scale) with various non-volatile storage, I think I do. You also fail to ask the most obvious before forcing your point ...  'How much space does he need, how often does the data change, what is the protocol..' etc etc, showing an complete lack of understanding for field programmability and maintenance.   In addition to say that you could hook together an SMD based solution more quickly than any 'Pi based (prototype) is asinine. Assuming a simple USB serial protocol, a 'Pi (or even a PC running Python) is 15-20 minutes work to write the software.

Comment: Yes, actually I have... which contrasts to real-world usage and deployments of sd-card based root filesystems  on a pi, which you obviously have not made, or you would realize as everyone else who has tried that has, what a nightmare sourcing sd cards with any longetivity as linux filesystems is.  If you seriously think that putting a QFP or QFN IC on a tiny PCB with a crystal and a few passives is hard, then you're not prepared to talk about making products.  Even apart from the reliability issue, have you tried to buy pi zeros in quantity?

Comment: I don't think putting together a small PCB with a micro and support components is hard. I do however think it's unproductive to so for small quantity production and asinine for just a few.    We obviously won't ever agree so let's leave it there, I'd simply suggest you do some reading on SD card FS (and FTL) http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/fs-for-embedded-full_0.pdf   ......If the problems you talk about were endemic where is the mass of product failures where they are using SD cards for storage. Everything from phones through tablets use them.

Comment: I believe the OP's idea of a cheap USB host is to get a MCU with flash storage with pre-formed bit sequences for USB reset,  enumeration, configuration, frames, in-out tokens, etc, and then simply dispatch the bit stream to two GPIO ports, thus emulating USB host to control a single particular FS device. This is how USB trainers/emulators work after capturing USB traffic with dedicated analyzer. It is possible.

Comment: @JackCreasey phones and tablets use sd cards for *auxiliary* storage of rarely touched files, and are battery powered so they do not often suffer unexpected power failures - that's a situation in which cards are moderately tolerable, but a *world of difference* from a line-powered Linux system that attempts to use one as a root file system - pretty much everyone who has tried to do *that* in a production deployment has had bad experiences.

Comment: @AliChen *emulating* a USB host at bit level is going to require higher spec hardware and be a lot harder than simply *using* the on-chip USB host peripheral of a cheap MCU that has it, such as the mentioned KL25Z.  At low-speed it might be possible with a generic MCU but at full speed it would require something rather specialized, while the on-chip peripheral "just works".

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes, that what I said in comments to the question above 15 hours ago. And yes, your suggestion for  KL25Z development PCB for $15 is hard to beat for a USB FS host function, provided that the host support software is available, affordable, and understandable.

Comment: It's more like $4 than $15 - the latter is only if you want a hobbyist targeted board.  And yes, the software is freely available.

Answer (score 0):

After all clarifications, the OP question boils down to the following formal request - how to build a FS USB embedded host. USB embedded hosts can restrict themselves to which class of peripherals to support. This request is to support a single peripheral, FT-232-style USB-to-UART converter, which is a valid restriction.

The solution, as usual, is full of trade-offs, depending on availability of software tools and skills of implementer. Even at full-speed, the solution would require a specialized USB hardware (aka USB PHY), which must be either built into MCU, of can be external over UTMI or ULPI bus. The serial USB interface requires special data "massage" (NRZI encoding, bit stuffing, and CRC calculations), and special handshake protocols (as IN-DATA-ACK), plus continuous periodic transmission of USB frames. Even at the 12 mbps rate this must be done at hardware level. Luckily, many commercial MCUs offer the USB host functionality, usually mislabeled as "USB OTG".

One solution is to use a full-blown ARM-based MCU (like certain models of Broadcomm based Raspberry Pi) that must be loaded with Linux-style operating system, which has nearly full plug-and-play support for most USB peripherals.

The other solution is to use a smaller MCU with "USB OTG" support, and implement the limited host functionality (singe device!) with custom-written embedded firmware. Companies as Texas instruments, Cypress, Microchip, NXP (and I am sure many more) are offering smaller MCU with "USB OTG" capability, mostly for FS (full-speed) rate. Unfortunately, the USB host functionality is usually (for some vague reason) not on the top of offered application examples, so the effort to implement the custom OTG might exceed the more universal and validated solution as full-blown Linux/Android approach.

Comments with links to particular "OTG host" firmware examples are definitely welcome.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @ChrisStratton, if you want to contribute something of substance, please post a link to any manufacturer supplied "OTG example" of code.

Comment: Stack exchange is not about links to external software (for reasons related to why the question itself is well on the way to off topic closure).  In terms of searching for something, you'll get a lot more useful results if you search for "USB host" which is the function contemplated, rather than "USB OTG" which is rarely supported by embedded stacks - ie, you either put a device mode firmware on the chip or a host mode one, but it's comparatively unusual on a system this small to have both at once as runtime options.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, so you can't present any published example which can serve a a basis of OTG host function development, correct? Then maybe you make like a tree...?

Comment: In fact, I can't think of any **OTG** examples, but as previously noted, you'll find plenty of embedded **host** examples in a web search.  Apparently SE bans LMGTFY links... which is fairly consistent with the limitation in purpose of this web site that you are failing to understand.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, maybe, maybe instead of lecturing me on a mission or else, you could simply post something like this: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-host-board-v2 ?

Comment: There's only one microcontroller with USB host support for FT232 proprietary protocol, which is FTDI's own Vinculum.  The other way to get support is via FTDI's drivers, which run on heavy OSes (Linux, Windows, Mac).  To talk to a USB-serial converter that uses the USB standard CDC profile there are more options.

Comment: @BenVoigt, actually, the referenced hobbytronic board appears to have a preinstalled software option for "Serial Driver for FTDI, CP210X or PL2303". I am not sure though how OP will  accommodate the preinstalled binaries to his control needs.